# Insert into table by selecting all from another and when a statement is true change the value in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, insert, case-when

So what I would like to do is take the values of a table (all of them) insert
them into a new one and when it meets any value that article identifier(sa.art_ident) replace it with the word bighead and the sa.art_moddate be replaced with the current system time. When ever I try to run it it tells me missing right parenthesis... Please help

```
PROCEDURE p_copier_one IS

     BEGIN
    INSERT INTO article_new
      (
        SELECT * FROM article_old sa
          CASE 
            WHEN sa.art_ident='%' THEN
            sa.art_ident = 'Bighead'
          END
        CASE
          WHEN sa.art_moddate='%' THEN
          sa.art_moddate = to_date(
                           '02/04/2012' 
                           ,'DD/MM/YYYY')
                           ,trunc(SYSDATE)

         END
          );



END p_copier_one;
```

Comment: You have to place your `CASE`statements between `SELECT` and `FROM` and name the other columns explicitly. You cannot use * here... Furthermore you might have to remove the parenthesis around the select part.

Comment: I know i am supposed to mark it as an answer, I just went to grab something to eat and the timer didn't allow me before doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. You would need to do something like shown below. Read my comments inline.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_copier_one
IS
BEGIN
  ---List down all your columns here. Although its option to mention your table column but its good practise. 
    INSERT INTO article_new (
        col1,
        col2,
        col3,
        col4,
        col5
    )
        SELECT col1,
               col2,
               --Put your case here
               CASE
                WHEN sa.art_ident = '%' THEN 'Bighead'
               END   col3,
               CASE
                WHEN sa.art_moddate = '%' THEN TO_DATE('02/04/2012','DD/MM/YYYY')
               END   col4,
               trunc(SYSDATE) col5
        FROM article_old sa;
COMMIT;        
END;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know you had to put every collumn individually. And i though c++ was hard with precise controls :/

Comment: `I didn't know you had to put every collumn individually` -- Its not mandatory to put every column name but its a good practice to put down. Also if you don't write then you will have to be 100% sure that your `Select` query have all the columns with same data type as of target table.

Comment: And if you don't write down the columns then every change in your database structure (new columns etc.) will break your code. So it's allways good to write them down...

Comment: If i don't want to add something to a column but leave it as it is, can i not put into Insert or put it on insert but not put it on select?

Comment: If you put column name explicitly in `INSERT` statement, that column should always be there in `SELECT` statement. If you leave, you get error. For rest all the scenarios, the best way to learn is to try your hands on.